# Spyder : how to make completion and documentation pop-up windows appear only on command

Tags: python, spyder, kite

I am using Spyder 4.0.1, and when I code windows with documentation/completions like the one below pop-up constantly. It's very distracting. However they do remain very useful when I need them!

So ***how can I configure spyder so that they ONLY appear when I press a macro/hotkey combination*** (instead of popping up unsolicited all the time)?

By the way I deactivated these windows by going to:

- "preferences/completion and linting/completion" and unticking:

  - Show completion details
  - Show completions on the fly
- "preferences/completion and linting/advanced" and unticking:

  - enable Kite
  - enable fallback completions

[image]

**EDIT**

As explained by Carlos Cordoba, activating "*enable fallback completions*" on its own enabled did not bring any pop-up windows unless I pressed Ctrl + Space. Perfect !

However "*enable Kite*" on its own makes the following windows pop-up as soon as I type a function name:

[image]

Maybe I did something bad in my setup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You don't need to deactive these options:

- Enable Kite
- Enable fallback completions

to get what you want. That's because by deactivating `Show completions on the fly`, completions will only be shown when pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>. *Note*: Several errors with fallback completions, and completions in general, will be fixed in our **4.1.0** version, to be released later in March 2020.

However, you need to deactivate the option called `Enable hover hints` (present in `Preferences > Completion and linting > Introspection`) to disable the extra information bubbles displayed in your first screenshot above. Unfortunately, there's no shortcut to show them at will because they depend on the mouse position.

Besides, to hide the bubbles shown after typing an open parenthesis (as displayed in your second screenshot), you need to deactivate the option called `Show calltips` (also present in `Preferences > Completion and linting > Introspection`).

Comment: Thank you for the pointers ! Hmmm... you were right about "Enable fallback completions" but "Enable Kite" still makes windows pop-up spontaneously; maybe a bug that would be fixed in the next update?

Comment: What windows are shown when "Enable Kite" is activated? Could you update your question above with them? Thanks!

Comment: I just updated the question with what you asked for. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks! But do you have Kite installed?

Comment: I think so: it says "Kite: ready" on the toolbar at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @Jeffery, I updated my answer to respond to your latest addition.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time ! Unfortunately Kite still shows me those windows after disabling "show calltips" ... I guess I won't use Kite for the moment.

Comment: What is the difference between `tab` and `cntr+space`? When I start typing an object name, they both seem to behave the same way. When I type a number and hit `tab`, I get 3 spaces. When I type a number and hit `cntrl+space`, I get an enormous list of keywords and text. I got tired of not being able to hit `enter` after typing a number (because Kite would always insert something), which is how I ended up on this thread. I still want the helpful suggestions, just not all the unhelpful ones (much more like Rstudio).

Comment: It also seems like in 4.2.2 the option "Show calltips" can be disabled, but the tips are still shown.